# How can I get computer status in c#

Tags: c#

I want to create something like a client in c#.

But I do not know that how I can learn computer status like sleep mode, off, logged in or logged out.

Also, I need to get the warning if the user haven't used the computer for 10 minutes.

Comment: `Off` is a _dead easy_ one! However, I would remove the "client" bit since that is extremely vague and irrelevant - while expanding on your problem of where you're at with determining the session mode, and lastly, recommend you ask your second question as another question.

Comment: this is a vaguely worded question.  Please try rephrasing with more information and a more specific question.  Also, you need to make it clear if you are trying to monitor the local PC the app is running on, or the status of another (remote) PC on the network.

Comment: actually when i write something stackoverflow doesnt accept it so it is short but basicly i want to monitor a local pc the app is running on,i will export all data into a database if there is a change mode

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about currently logged user and how to hook the Locked/Unlocked events [in this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/770957-get-computer-state-locked-stand-c).

There are some other different approaches you might try:

1. You can use the `System.Diagnostics` and get the process list via `Processes.GetProcesses()`. Just keep an eye on the Idle process -- if it runs for more than 50% CPU longer than 10 mins the user seems to be idling too.
2. You can use [Performance Counters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx) to monitor the activity taking place on the computer and make certain decisions.
3. You can also use the [WMI service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with similar purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: 
User activity/inactivity can be monitored using hooks. Start a timer with a 10-minute interval. Whenever you detect a keyboard/mouse message, restart it. If the timer event happens, than you detected 10 minutes of inactivity.